# Enabling editing for TStringGrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I am making a simple database application by following this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=416qL6is5Xw#t=204s). My problem occurs when I use a `TStringGrid` instead of a `TGrid` as stated the video because I don't have it. I have a Navigator and  all of my data loaded into the `TStringGrid`, but I am unable to edit it at all. So far I've tried double clicking an entry, pressing F2 and clicking on the Edit button on the Navigator, but nothing is working.

Is there anything I need to alter in the properties of the `TStringGrid` to allow editing or is the purpose of it only to display data?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `goEditing` to the `Options` property. Include it in the Object Inspector, or in code:

```
StringGrid1.Options := StringGrid1.Options + [goEditing];
```

Comment: and `goRowSelect` must be removed from the `Options` property too.